# How to compare a date in custom field with today's date in custom WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I have a list of competitions for which I set deadlines using Wordpress' built-in custom fields, in a YYYYMMDD format. I want to create a custom loop to display only the competitions that are now closed, meaning that their deadlines are older than today's date.

I tried doing the following, but this displays all competitions, both open and closed:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'deadline',
        'value' => date( 'Ymd' ), 
        'compare' => '=<',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
);

$open_comps = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on my own. You also need to specify the 'meta_key' parameter in the query's arguments, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'deadline',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'deadline',
        'value' => date( 'Ymd' ), 
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )
);

$open_comps = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'type' => 'date',
    'compare' => '<='

  )
```

hope is useful for it.